Elasticsearch fleet server falling to 'unhealthy'
I have 2-node Elasticsearch on-prem cluster. 1/2 nodes, besides Elasticsearch, hosts also Kibana + Logstash. OS for both nodes is Ubuntu server 24.04. Both transport (TCP - 9200) and cluster network (TCP-9300) use self-signed certs based on CA created with elasticsearch-certutil. I am planning to deploy integrations en-masse on this solution. As integrations need agents, I aim for fleet server (FS). The FS installation should be straightforward as offered in Kibana's GUI:
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/elastic-agent/elastic-agent- 
8.15.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzvf elastic-agent-8.15.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd elastic-agent-8.15.3-linux-x86_64
sudo ./elastic-agent install \
  --fleet-server-es=https://10.x.y.z:9200 \
  --fleet-server-service-token= AAEAAWVsYXN0aWMvZmxlZXQtc2VydmVyL3Rva2VuLTE3MzEwNjk2Nzk1NjQ6TzJSNXRQR05RVE9hWk9ld00wc2Zldw \
  --fleet-server-policy=fleet-server-policy \
  --fleet-server-es-ca-trusted-fingerprint=2DFA26BD931CA5E4FA29C63BDA41F0E6EC45CED1CF05AF6DDCA9D9FE01AA3E53 \
  --fleet-server-port=8220 --base-path /elk/fleet_server

The elastic-agent representing fleet server is "healthy" few minutes after installation, then goes to unhealthy. It gets back to a healthy state after systemctl restart elastic-agent temporarily (for only few minutes).
I combed through every log I could think of on my Linux system, to no avail. Where to look for diagnostics telling me what is wrong?

I had this error on ubuntu 20.04 single node as ELK 7.17.25 server and a win 11 with elastic-agent 7.17.25. After a bout 15 minutes, agent status gone unhealthy. Elastic agent has no full support for win 11 (Base on This link)
I read this page but Elastic Agent has full support for Ubuntu 24.04.
It is not bad decision to check this:
Go to Kibana > Endpoints > Click on Policy status of that End point and check all the Policy Responses to be Success. Maybe you have a problem there.
